# GLM code/logistic regression is taking too long to run

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, lme4

I am trying to run the following code. My computer keeps getting frozen when I try to run it. Therefore, I can see the correlation matrices, I am unable to view the results of the GLM/data arrays.

```
# running the assay


#which_p_value = "x1"
which_p_value = "groupcategory"
#which_p_value = "x1:groupcategory"

run_anova = FALSE 
simulate_mixed_effect = TRUE 
mixed_effect_sd = 3.094069
mixed_effect_sd_slope = 3.098661

library(tidyverse)
n_people <- c(2,5,10,15,20)
coef1 <- 1.61
coef2 <- -0.01
#coef3 <- 5
#coef4 <- 0

g1 = 0
g2 = 1
g3 = 2 
distances <- c(60,90,135,202.5,303.75,455.625)/100
n_trials <- 35
oneto1000 <- 25
n_track_lengths <- length(distances)
groupcategory = c(rep(g1, n_track_lengths), rep(g2, n_track_lengths),rep(g3,n_track_lengths))
z = c(n_people)
emptydataframeforpowerplots = NULL

coef3s <- c(-5, -4, -3, -2,-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
coef4s <- c(-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)

Datarray <- array(dim=c(length(coef3s), length(coef4s),length(n_people)))

coef3_counter =1
for (coef3 in coef3s) {
  coef4_counter =1
  for (coef4 in coef4s) {
    z1_g2 <- coef1 + coef2*distances + coef3*g2 + coef4*g2*distances
    z1_g3 <- coef1 + coef2*distances + coef3*g3 + coef4*g3*distances
    d = NULL
    pr1 = 1/(1+exp(-z1_g2))
    pr2 = 1/(1+exp(-z1_g3))

    counter=1
    for (i in n_people) {
      for (j in 1:oneto1000){
        df <- c()
        for (k in 1:i){

          # random effect from drawing a random intercept with sd = x

          if (simulate_mixed_effect){
            coef1_r = rnorm(1, mean=coef1, sd=mixed_effect_sd)
            coef2_r = rnorm(1, mean=coef1, sd=mixed_effect_sd_slope)
          } else {
            coef1_r = coef1
            coef2_r = coef2
          }

          z_g1 <- coef1_r + coef2*distances + coef3*g1 + coef4*g1*distances
          pr = 1/(1+exp(-z_g1))

          z1_g2 <- coef1_r + coef2*distances + coef3*g2 + coef4*g2*distances
          pr1 = 1/(1+exp(-z1_g2))

          if (run_anova) {
            df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x1 = c(rep(distances, 3)),
                                     y = c(rbinom(n_track_lengths,n_trials,pr), rbinom(n_track_lengths,n_trials,pr1),rbinom(n_track_lengths,n_trials,pr2)),
                                     groupcategory = groupcategory, id = c(rep(k,18))))

          } else { # this is for glmer data organisation
            for (m in 1:n_trials) {
            df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x1 = c(rep(distances, 3)),
 y = c(rbinom(n_track_lengths,1,pr),rbinom(n_track_lengths,1,pr1),rbinom(n_track_lengths,1,pr2)),groupcategory = groupcategory,id = c(rep(k,18))))

            }
          }
        }

        if (run_anova) {
          #df_aov <- aov(y~x1*groupcategory+Error(id/(x1*groupcategory)),data=df)
          #df_aov_sum <- summary(df_aov)
          #pvalue <- df_aov_sum[[5]][[1]][which_p_value,"Pr(>F)"]

          df_aov <- aov(y~x1*groupcategory+Error(id),data=df)
          df_aov_sum <- summary(df_aov)
          pvalue <- df_aov_sum[[2]][[1]][which_p_value, "Pr(>F)"]
        } 
 checkme <- df %>% group_by(groupcategory,id) %>% summarise(miny=min(y),maxy=max(y)) %>% mutate(expectfail = miny==maxy)
else { 
          mod_group_glmer <-  glmer(y ~ x1 + groupcategory + (1+x1|id), data = df, family = "binomial")
          sum <- summary(mod_group_glmer)
          pvalue <- sum$coefficients[which_p_value, "Pr(>|z|)"]
        }

        d = rbind(d,data.frame(pvalue))
      }
      count <- plyr::ldply(d,function(c) sum(c<=0.05))
      Datarray[coef3_counter,coef4_counter,counter] <- count$V1/oneto1000
      counter = counter +1
      d = NULL
    }
    coef4_counter = coef4_counter + 1
  }
  coef3_counter = coef3_counter + 1
}
```

Does anybody have any advice on how I can overcome this issue? I have tried different things such as lowering the range of sample sizes (n_people) but I have still been unsuccessful. My computer starts making a whirring noise and eventually I am forced to have to 'force quit' the program?

Comment: A couple general comments: (a) Don't grow objects in loops. Code like `d <- rbind(d, ....)` is much slower than having `d` already the right size and running `d[i, ] <- ...`, and that is slower than accumulating results in a list `d_list[[i]] <- ...` and turning the list into a data frame at the very end `d <- bind_rows(d_list)`. See [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) (free PDF) for a longer discussion.

Comment: (b) Looks like you have 11 values each of `coef3s` and `coef4s`, 5 values of  `n_people`, and 25 values of `oneto1000`, which gives `11 * 11 * 5 * 25 = 15125` individual mixed effects regressions your planning to run. If they take 0.5 seconds each, that's still over 2 hours just to fit the models, so make sure you have reasonable expectations for how long to wait. Running in parallel could help speed this up quite a bit. (And it might be taking over 0.5 seconds...)

Comment: (c) Other things look vaguely inefficient. The `plyr` package isn't known for speed, so when I see you use `ldply` for a simple function, and then you only use one component of the result, that could be an inefficiency. **But** when trying to speed up code, you should profile it to see what the slow parts are and work on those. Maybe `ldply` takes 20 milliseconds per iteration, and we could reduce that to 1 ms with another method, but if each iteration takes 2 secs that speed up of 19 ms isn't noticeable. [Here's a chapter on profiling code in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).

Comment: 6 nested for loops? What do you expect? And you don't ever seem to change the value of `run_anova`. If you suspect your code is Frozen, try adding a progress bar, or a simple `cat` statement.